# VPS internet has been killed. How do I fix it?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vps, ifconfig

I am working with a friend on a VPS we use. Recently out root password was leaked and out internet has been completely ruined. ifconfig wan't recognised as a valid command or anything.

I managed to edit /etc/profile using our master VM VNC connection, and I now have ifconfig working, after adding /sbin to the PATH. I have tried several VPS and network restarts, but no matter how hard I try I can't get ping 8.8.8.8 to connect to anything. It just sits there until termination and then says 100% packet loss. eth0 is up, and has the correct IP and all other info. What do I do? I need to get files off of the VPS at the very least, and my only way to do that would be a physical transcription or through the internet.

Thanks for responses!

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I feel there's such a huge range of possible scenarios that you might be better off looking at alternative ways of recovering data. How much data are we talking here? And is there any chance your VPS host would be willing to pull files off for you? Try contacting their support.

Comment: If it's a full VM VPS (e.g. KVM) they might not be able to pull files. In that case, ask them if they can let you download the disk image, or attach it as a data disk on a new VM (which you might have to pay for). Oh! Does your VNC connection let you insert media? You might be able to boot off a recovery disk. Or ask the provider if they can boot into a rescue environment for you. This is assuming it's a full VM and not a container e.g. OpenVZ.

Comment: @Bob I can take a snapshot of the VPS but I cannot download the files. If possible I'd like to get the networking online so I can get the VPS running as soon as possible

Comment: Have you asked the VPS provider about whether they disabled your network access for security reasons?

Comment: @grawity No, I haven't. We were DDoS ed , however last time this exact issue happened, reinstalling fixed everything, so I believe the network issue and the DDoS was a coincidence. Our Ethernet link says it is up, and it has the correct IP, so I don't think we're being cut off

Comment: @bob Provider can't do anything without a restored connection - and we can fix it ourselves with that

Comment: The presence of an IP address means nothing; the actual connection could still be disabled in a dozen different ways by the provider. (In other words, you cannot make that conclusion.)

Comment: @grawity I've taken a snapshot of the broken machine and I am now reinstalling. If this fixes the issue i'll have to work out a solution. For now I will attempt to close this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific to be useful to the broader community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases, your provider will either manually or automatically throttle or disable your VPS's internet connection to protect the provider's bandwidth usage. Asking my provider had them immediately turn back on the connection.